# Programmatically add Command of Parent ViewModel to a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on an application which uses MVVM but I have a little Problem. 
In one ViewModel I need to create some buttons programatically and bind them to a command which lives in a parent ViewModel.

I have a CommandHelper which implements the ICommand interface and so I have the following in the parent ViewModel.

```
public CommandHelper<string> NavCommand { get; private set; }
public MainWindowViewModel(ButtonGridViewModel buttonGridViewModel,
                                   ConfigViewModel configViewModel)
{
    // Some inits
    ...

    NavCommand = new CommandHelper<string>(OnNavCommand);
}

private void OnNavCommand(string target)
{
    if (_ViewModels.ContainsKey(target) && CurrentViewModel != _ViewModels[target])
    {
       LastViewModel = CurrentViewModel;
       CurrentViewModel = _ViewModels[target];
    }
}
```

In the other ViewModel in the method where I generate the buttons I tried:

```
Binding commandBinding = new Binding();
commandBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("NavCommand");
commandBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(MainWindowViewModel), 1);
btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, commandBinding);
btn.CommandParameter = "ConfigViewModel";
```

But the I never reach the command this way... If I try to use a Command located in the generating ViewModel I can use it without a problem when I don't use the RelativeSource.

I hope someone had this problem before and can give me a proper hint how to reach the command in the parent ViewModel, because I don't want to fire an event where I bint to in the parent ViewModel...

I am pretty sure that some it works, if I do similar tasks in XAML I can bind to a parents command but programmatically I have a little problem...

Greetings 
Marlie

Comment: A view model instance is never an ancestor of a view element, hence RelativeSource won't work. Set the Source property of the Binding to the appropriate view model instance.

Comment: So if I get you right I should give the instance of my MainViewModel into the ButtonGridViewModel by e.g. DI and just bind it there ... ok not that solution I was looking for but ok if its the solution I'll test it, even if I was hoping there was a somehow nicer way of doing it. But thanks so far Clemens.